# cant delete the first row in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The below delete works fine except when the I try to delete the first row of the table using the below function. What happens is that the browser doesnt redirect to the delete function (no error).This seems to be a quirk as the delete function works fine for every other row. The problem is only the first row of the table and I can delete the first row manually from mysql. I have no idea why it does this.

```
//view  

<?= $this->Form->postLink('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> ',  ['action' => 'delete', $item->id],
   [   'escape' => false, 'confirm' => __('Are you sure, you want to delete {0}?', $item->id)  ]) ?>

//controller
public function delete($id = null)
    {

       $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $schedulestudent = $this->Schedulestudents->get($id);
        if ($this->Schedulestudents->delete($schedulestudent)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The schedulestudent has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The schedulestudent could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'studentschedule']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the postlink before this command below. So I should have closed the form first after reading more about this on the cake3 form manual.  I cant have postlinks in form blocks

echo $this->Form->end();